How do I triggers or initialize a function before the child component being rendered?
I want to implement a feature that requires a top component to access static object data from child component before the child component is being rendered.
Is it possible to achieve this in React Js or with State Management?
I tried with React context it works only when component rendered

I think the question requires more context but from what I can understand, using forwardRef might help you. forwardRef can be used to expose DOM nodes and functions to the parent component.
If forwardRef doesn't work you can do something like below:
function ParentComponent() {
  const [isChildRendered, setIsChildRendered] = useState(false);

  const handleChildRender = (isRendered) => {
    setIsChildRendered(isRendered);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent onRender={handleChildRender} />
    </div>
  );
}

and in the child component:
function ChildComponent({ onRender }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Call the parent's callback function to notify that the child is rendered
    onRender(true);

    // Clean-up function to notify the parent when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      onRender(false);
    };
  }, [onRender]);

  return <div>This is the child component</div>;
}

You can use this method to pass the function to onRender function or use the isChildRendered state to execute some code.
